# Java : Possible to store multiple hash maps inside a string array?

Tags: java, arrays, list, dictionary, hash

Title says it all but for the sake of example.. I'm currently learning Java now and as a personal experiment I'm writing a soft representation of an ATM screen.

I'm attempting to store three hash maps inside of one value within a list of arrays.  Thus, giving me the ability to add multiple strings, all containing their own set of three maps.

So - I want an Array List for "User" and within this list, will be three maps for "Checking" "Saving" and "CDs".

When adding a new User, this user is also given the ability to add/modify/remove three different "accounts."

Thoughts?

Comment: No. You can store multiple hash maps in an array of hash maps, and multiple strings in an array of strings, but not multiple hash maps in an array of strings, because hash maps aren't strings.

Comment: @AndyTurner sure you can, e.g JSON

Comment: @nafas that's a map, not a hash map.

Comment: @AndyTurner he could do it if he wrapped that map in a JAVA class.

Comment: @Agronis  you may want to consider using JSON. it does what you need

Comment: @AndyTurner haha sorry mate, it was meant to be for Agronis :D

Comment: You will do much better if you declare a `User` class which has fields for the user's accounts.

Comment: Appreciate the thoughts.. I did find this to work..

`public class User {
    double check;
    double save;
    double cd;
}

   public A() {
        User u = new User();
        HashMap<String, User> users = new HashMap();
        users.put("Agronis", u);
    }
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if it could help you solve the problem

```
HashMap <String,HashMap> holder = new HashMap<>();
HashMap <Integer,Integer> hm1 = new HashMap<>();
HashMap <Integer,String> hm2 = new HashMap<>();
hm1.put(0,10000000);
hm1.put(1,5000);
hm2.put(0,"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx");
hm2.put(1,"yyyy-yyyy-yyyy");

holder.put("Amt", hm1);
holder.put("Info", hm2);

Iterator<String> iterator = holder.keySet().iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext())
{String key = iterator.next();
 System.out.println("key: " + key + " value: " + holder.get(key));
}
```

Output:

key: Amt value: {0=10000000, 1=5000}

key: Info value: {0=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, 1=yyyy-yyyy-yyyy}

you can 1st fetch the desired field like Amt using the key1 and then use the key2 (0,1,2....)
for each person to fetch corresponding value.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.